# Laravel route doesn't return controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am a newbie to Laravel. I trying o learn it.

I got stuck in this.
I want to return to the `routes.php` a controller that returns a view.
I have `WelcomeController.php` and welcome.blade.php and `contact.blade.php`.

That's my files

routes.php:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|

*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return 'WelcomeController@index';
});

Route::get('/contact', function () {
    return "WelcomeController@contact";
});
```

WelcomeController.php :

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class WelcomeController extends Controller
{
   /**
     * Instantiate a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */


public function index() {
    return view('welcome');
}

public function contact() {
    return view('contact');
}
}

?>
```

Where I am getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your routes to

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

and

```
Route::get('/contact', 'WelcomeController@contact');
```

If you don't have any logic on a page and want to skip the controller you can use [View routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#view-routes) to directly show a view:

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
```

and

```
Route::view('/contact', 'contact');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way.
In `routes\web.php`

```
Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
```

In Controller as it's,

```
class WelcomeController extends Controller
{

 public function index() {
 return view('welcome');
 }

 public function contact() {
 return view('contact');
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|

*/

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

Route::get('/contact', 'AWelcomeController@contact');
```

Or if you don't have anything to pass on the view you can use

```
Route::view('/', 'welcome');
Route::view('/contact', 'contact');
```